# Whats the difference between "-" in - (void) and "+" in + (id) or + (scene) for Objective-c?

Tags: void, scene

As the question stated, I was confusing what the symbol - and + mean when writing a method?
Thanks

Comment: What language are you talking about?

Comment: Please do not assume that we have prior knowledge about the topic to which you're referring. What language, and what specific syntax are you asking about the use of? The void and scene tags you decided to use are meaningless without more information.

Comment: Oh sorry, Objective-C for cocos2d

Answer (score 1):

"-" means instance method
"+" means class method

For e.g. NSNumber class defines several initializers, including:

```
- (id)initWithInt:(int)value;
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithInt:(int)value;
```

First one is instance method second one is class method.

```
NSNumber *magicNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:42];
NSNumber *magicNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:42];
```

Regarding "id"

```
+ (id)alloc;
```

This is a special keyword used in Objective-C to mean “some kind of object.” It is a pointer to an object, like (NSObject *), but is special in that it doesn’t use an asterisk.

Refer https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW7